# Error installing to Parse: name=vfs://.... JBoss AS 6 error

Tags: java, jboss6.x

When I try to deploy `.ear` files of my application in a `JBoss AS 6` I get following errors. 
Like below.
`[AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfs://`
`org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: vfs://`

Full error log..

```
ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfs:///home/abcd/trade/JBoss_Migration_Related/JBoss/jboss-6.1.0.Final_MFG/server/default/deploy/abcd_RMS-1.0.ear state=PreParse mode=Manual requiredState=Parse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfs:///home/abcd/trade/JBoss_Migration_Related/JBoss/jboss-6.1.0.Final_MFG/server/default/deploy/abcd_RMS-1.0.ear/abcdRMS.war/
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:383) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:343) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:315) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:255) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: vfs:///home/abcd/trade/JBoss_Migration_Related/JBoss/jboss-6.1.0.Final_MFG/server/default/deploy/abcd_RMS-1.0.ear/abcdOMSAdmin.war/WEB-INF/web.xml@105,11
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:224) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:178) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:257) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:231) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:137) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:121) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:352) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:334) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:251) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:369) [:2.2.2.GA]
... 48 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: The content of element type "web-app" must match "(icon?,display-name?,description?,distributable?,context-param*,filter*,filter-mapping*,listener*,servlet*,servlet-mapping*,session-config?,mime-mapping*,welcome-file-list?,error-page*,taglib*,resource-env-ref*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,login-config?,security-role*,env-entry*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*)". @ vfs:///home/abcd/trade/JBoss_Migration_Related/JBoss/jboss-6.1.0.Final_MFG/server/default/deploy/abcd_RMS-1.0.ear/abcdOMSAdmin.war/WEB-INF/web.xml[105,11]
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.error(SaxJBossXBParser.java:416) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:209) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
... 57 more
```

How can I resolve this matter ? 
I'm using Java for my application (JDK 1.6)
And `JBoss` is in a `linux environment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 3rd exception that you'r getting, `org.xml.sax.SAXException`, Reason is you don't match the fields correctly in your web-app.xml file. You need to match the order of the fields according to the standard order. Order is given in the exception itself.

`(icon?,display-name?,description?,distributable?,context-param*,filter*,filter-mapping*,listener*,servlet*,servlet-mapping*,session-config?,mime-mapping*,welcome-file-list?,error-page*,taglib*,resource-env-ref*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,login-config?,security-role*,env-entry*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*)`