# What is "Error installing to Parse: name=vfs://.." in JBoss 6.1.0 AS

Tags: java, jboss6.x

I got this error when I try to start the `JBoss AS 6.1.0`. What could be the reason for that ? In what cases that error appears ?

Comment: Why posting the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673420/error-installing-to-parse-name-vfs-jboss-as-6-error

Comment: No actually I want to know the reason why JBoss give this error. In my previous question it is more focused on my code and it's related issues. Yes the question topic has the error message though.

Comment: Uh you get that when there is something wrong. You'd have to be a whole lot more specific in your questioning if you want a specific answer.

Comment: @Gimby : please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673420/error-installing-to-parse-name-vfs-jboss-as-6-error) I got this error in my project.

Comment: That is a given, you do not get the error just by sitting on your chair doing nothing. This particular non-specific question remains unanswerable.

Comment: @Gimby : so can you suggest a way to be more specific :)

Comment: Yes: think about your question from the perspective of the people who you want to answer: CAN they answer it or not? If the answer is "probably not, this has no identifiable context whatsoever", don't hit the post button. Wait until you have something that actually makes sense.

Comment: @Gimby : actually I'm new to this area (JBoss) I thought this as a regular exception/error like we have in Java (Null pointer .. etc) if so someone can tell me why it's appearing. I post that previous question and didn't get any helpful answer except for one. That is why  I posted this. If I can get an Idea about this error then I can search more on my own. And I'm not sitting on my chair and do nothing. That is even why I posted these questions. :) And thanks for your advice. sorry if I done something wrong here.